# Making Yarn dynamically allocate resources for Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, scheduler, hadoop2

I have a cluster managed with Yarn and runs Spark jobs, the components were installed using Ambari (2.6.3.0-235). I have 6 hosts each with 6 cores. I use Fair scheduler

I want Yarn to automatically add/remove executor cores, but no matter what I do it doesn't work

Relevant Spark configuration (configured in Ambari):

```
spark.dynamicAllocation.schedulerBacklogTimeout 10s
spark.dynamicAllocation.sustainedSchedulerBacklogTimeout 5s
spark.driver.memory 4G
spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled true
spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors 6 (has no effect - starts with 2)
spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors 10
spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors 1
spark.scheduler.mode FAIR
spark.shuffle.service.enabled true
SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY="36G"
```

Relevant Yarn configuration (configured in Ambari):

```
yarn.nodemanager.aux-services mapreduce_shuffle,spark_shuffle,spark2_shuffle
YARN Java heap size 4096
yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.fair.FairScheduler
yarn.scheduler.fair.preemption true
yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.spark2_shuffle.class org.apache.spark.network.yarn.YarnShuffleService 
yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.spark2_shuffle.classpath {{stack_root}}/${hdp.version}/spark2/aux/*
yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.spark_shuffle.class org.apache.spark.network.yarn.YarnShuffleService
yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.spark_shuffle.classpath {{stack_root}}/${hdp.version}/spark/aux/*
Minimum Container Size (VCores) 0
Maximum Container Size (VCores) 12 
Number of virtual cores 12
```

Also I followed [Dynamic resource allocation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#dynamic-resource-allocation) and passed all the steps to configure external shuffle service, I copied the yarn-shuffle jar:

```
cp /usr/hdp/2.6.3.0-235/spark/aux/spark-2.2.0.2.6.3.0-235-yarn-shuffle.jar /usr/hdp/2.6.3.0-235/hadoop-yarn/lib/
```

I see only 3 cores are allocated to the application (deafult executors is 2 so I guess its driver+2) the queue:

[image]

Although many tasks are pending:

[image]

Comment: While submitting spark application override the below spark config properties and try. spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true and spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true in your application code.

Comment: @SumanDas both of those settings were configured as you can see in the configuration description. Also, I passed over all the steps of the external shuffle configuration according to the official Spark manual

Comment: Just wanted to know did you try to pass the above parameters while submitting spark jobs. or did you tried setting it in your spark config. The snippet you shared above shows you have done the changes at the server level. We did the same thing in our spark cluster in yarn mode it worked. Can you also please share your code for spark submit. Also which version of spark you are using?

Comment: Enable WARN logging level for org.apache.spark.util.Utils logger to see what happens inside.
Add the following line to conf/log4j.properties:
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.util.Utils=WARN Also share the spark.executor.instances count